# Several properties are unavailable in .NET6 WinExe Post-Build

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-5, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to run a post-build step for a VS C# WinExe project, and noticed that many properties that I expected to be available are not: specifically, ProjectDir, ProjectPath, OutDir, and TargetDir. These values *are* present in a DLL project in the same solution. Is there a way to make them available for the exe?

Here are my project settings:

```
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

And the post-build:

```
echo Configuration: "$(Configuration)"
echo SolutionDir: "$(SolutionDir)"
echo ProjectDir: "$(ProjectDir)"
echo ProjectPath: "$(ProjectPath)"
echo OutDir: "$(OutDir)"
echo TargetDir: "$(TargetDir)"
```

And the output:

```
2>Configuration: "Debug"
2>SolutionDir: "C:\git\EtmsConnectionSelectorFramework\"
2>ProjectDir: ""
2>ProjectPath: ""
2>OutDir: ""
2>TargetDir: ""
```

Comment: Works on my machine, you'll need to say more about how the project differs from, say, the Winforms project template.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem: I assumed the syntax for the post-build event in the csproj file was the same as for net48 projects, but it is not.

I was using:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <PostBuildEvent>
      <!-- commands go here -->
```

But the syntax should have been:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command=" (commands go here) " />
```

I'm a little surprised that the first attempt ran at all, instead of just failing to see values for certain properties. Regardless, it's working now.